# Magmi stuck on one CSV

Tags: magento, csv, magmi

The problem is that Magmi keeps searching for the same file (example: `file1.csv`) when I run the import for another file (example: `file2.csv`).
No matter how many files I upload and try to save as default, when I run import and check the results the only thing I see is one error, and it says: `Can't find file1.csv`

I've deleted all the files in `var/import`, uploaded `file2.csv` again and tried to save profile and run import - the same thing happens. Magmi keeps searching for `file1.csv` instead of `file2.csv`.

The error that Magmi gives in red says:

> Fopen (long url) Failed to open stream: permission denied

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the file permissions of your csv are correct.

To be sure, chmod your csv file to **644**

Answer (score 0):

Magmi stores its configuration settings in the directory magmi/conf so this has to be writeable. The last csv files used are stored in the file Magmi_CSVDataSource.conf. Have a look in there to see what file it thinks it's using. Try manually updating it to check Magmi is working properly.

Be sure to be pointing at the right directory too.